# How to perform two sampled Kolmogorv-Smirnov test?

Tags: r, python, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have two samples say `x` and `y`. Now I want to perform two sampled Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. My null hypothesis is `H0: F(x) = F(y)` and alternative hypothesis is `H1: F(x) > F(y)`. Most of the available packages considers `H0: F(x) = F(y)` and `H1:F(x) ≠ F(y)` or `H0: F(x) ≥ F(y)` and `H1:F(x) < (y)` or `H0: F(x) <= F(y)` and `H1:F(x) > (y)`. So please help to perform the test or suggest any available code.

```
 X: [0.637678459, 0.839899847, 0.376087864, 0.64691877, 0.837050283, 0.363882241, 0.640549397, 0.843420768, 0.367980669, 0.643326399, 0.845545384, 0.357465934, 0.640676349, 0.8403466190000001, 0.35925559100000004, 0.638325163, 0.840292722, 0.360516998, 0.642264568, 0.8397287940000001, 0.35860865299999994, 0.639052463, 0.840447197]

Y: [0.649833143, 0.8353442940000001, 0.376087864, 0.643562512, 0.8496916059999999, 0.363882241, 0.642279421, 0.84112995, 0.36664778299999995, 0.633664154, 0.844208898, 0.357461322, 0.640149393, 0.8404260240000001, 0.35925559100000004, 0.638325163, 0.840292722]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your only problem is that the software's only allowed one-sided alternative goes in the wrong direction, simply negate all your data (i.e. multiply by -1) and use the alternative in the other direction to the one you wanted.

Note that R offers both direction of alternative.

It's very important to note that with the one sided test, it's perfectly possible to get rejection for both $H_{1a}: F_X(x) > F_Y(x)$ and $H_{1b}: F_X(x) < F_Y(x)$ $^{**}$ since both are only for "at least one value" for $x$.

If you're looking for an alternative like stochastic dominance you may want to look to a different test.

** you may like to ponder the differences between the way you wrote the hypotheses and the way I wrote the hypotheses; the difference is important

Comment: (+1) I think there's perhaps also the question of the difference between the nulls $H_0: F_X(x) = F_Y(x)$ & $F_X(x)\leq F_Y(x)$. (I can't see how the latter formulation makes sense as a null unless you take it as being "for all $x$"; else, as you point out, it wouldn't preclude $F_X(x)>F_Y(X)$ for some $x$.)

Comment: if the null hypothesis is H0: F(x) = F(y) and alternative hypothesis is H1: F(x) > F(y) or H1: F(x) < F(y) then what changes should be made from the conventional hypothesis? @Glen_b @ Scortchi - Reinstate Monica

Comment: Doesn't negation work only when $F$ is symmetric about $0$?

Comment: It reverses the sort order of the observations, which is in turn the only thing that impacts the value of the two-sample test statistic, converting relationships between cdfs from < to > and vice versa (swapping from looking below to above for example). Symmetry doesn't come into it.

Comment: Per [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9jA2.png) (the values were sampled from exponential distributions -- the issue I was talking about doesn't rely on symmetry of either F; it lets you use a one-sided KS test that looks "the wrong way" to go the other way)

Comment: @abcxyz you don't need any changes to the test; it relies on dealing with the null distribution under equality

Comment: @abcxyz: Even if your test is $H_0:\forall x\ F_X(x) \leq F_Y(x)$ vs $H_1: \exists x\ F_X(x) > F_Y(x)$, you'll calculate the probability of exceeding an observed difference in the empirical distributions in the direction of the alternative under $H0: \forall F_X(x) = F_Y(x)$, the particular null that's most compatible with the observations.